# Logic app fails when calling Azure Function. How can I embed authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Function that requires authentication.  I'm calling it from a Logic App, but I'm unsure how to embed the required authentication key in the logic designer.

How do I make an authenticated call from a Logic App to an Azure function?

Answer (score 1):

One known issue is that Logic Apps don't work with Function Apps that have slots enabled.

If you're in that situation, delete the Azure App Setting called `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` (which will be set the `Blob`), and stop using slots.

This is tracked by https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1752.

Comment: Interesting read! But, how does this answer the question of embedding authentication?

Comment: Logic apps have direct support for calling Azure Functions, so you don't need to worry about auth. I was mentioning the one case that's broken today

Answer (score 1):

So I was just using this url for the function integration:

```
"uri": "https://%name%.azurewebsites.net/api/%route%?code=YOUR_SECRET_GOES_HERE"
```

where %name% and %route% are placeholders for your actual values and obviously `YOUR_SECRET_GOES_HERE` is a placeholder for your secret